# Why Azure (Durable) Function Activity in Azure Data Factory is 'NotFound'? - 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException'

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

I have Azure Durable Function developed in VS Code.
Http Start route binding in function.json is " "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}"
This works locally fine.

I have now deployed to Azure. Name of orchestration trigger is "MyOrchestrator"

I'm now trying to call this function from Azure Data Factory.
Function name configured as "orchestrators/MyOrchestrator". I tried also "MyOrchestrator".

I wonder what is wrong. Is this compatibility issue? Authorization issue?

I get error when debuging in ADF:

```
 Call to provided Azure function 'MyOrchestrator' failed with status-'NotFound' and 
    message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.
```

Error in Application Insight:

```
   Exception while executing function: Functions.MyHttpStart Result: Failure
Exception: Exception: {'Message': 'Something went wrong while processing your request', 'ExceptionMessage': 'Forbidden', 'ExceptionType': 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException', 'StackTrace': '   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n
```

Error in Application Insight

```
   Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
```

host.json is:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add

1. Function App Url (you can find this in function app overview page)
2. Function Key

under Azure function linked service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).